# How can I create table in bash output, that shows every item about specific user?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have simple bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

grep home /etc/passwd | grep $1
```

that shows information about user, 
    example of output:

```
 Vladislav:x:1000:1000:Vladislav,,,:/home/vladislav:/bin/bash
```

Is it possible to make it look like [table (example screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWjJc.png) ? I mean - with 2 columns and 
simple separator between rows

Comment: Do you want the spelling mistakes from the screen shot too?  Do you expect the box lines?  Do you expect the variable-width font?

Answer (score 0):

if all you want is columns you can format it like:

```
grep home /etc/passwd | grep $1 | sed 's/:/ /g' | awk '{NAME=$1;ENC=$2;AMT=3;MIN=$4;$1=$2=$3=$4="";print "name\t"NAME"\nEncrypted password\t"ENC"\nAmount of days\t"AMT"\nMinimum count of days\t"MIN"\nOther item description\t"$0}'
```

This will take your original output, replace the `:` with a literal space then feed it into awk and format your "table".

The output I get from your sample input string is:

```
name    Vladislav
Encrypted password  x
Amount of days  3
Minimum count of days   1000
Other item description      Vladislav,,, /home/vladislav /bin/bash
```